# iOS: How to display a list of content dynamically rendered from JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

Much like the Twitter timeline which populates dynamically, I need to populate my homescreen with list of content from fetched JSON metadata (img urls and text descriptions)

It should look something like this.

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| image1  | Text description..... |
+---------+-----------------------+
| image2  | Text description..... |
+---------+-----------------------+
| image3  | Text description..... |
+---------+-----------------------+
| image4  | Text description..... |
+---------+-----------------------+
...
+---------+-----------------------+
| image10 | Text description..... |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

I'm just starting with GUI development on iOS and I can't seem to find any useful info about displaying dynamic content on iOS devices. I'll greatly appreciate useful info.

Answer (score 3):

Use UITableViewController. Load the JSON into a dictionary (or whatever data structure you are using) and then display the data that way.  The controller will handle creating each cell for each entry in your data structure.

Here is a tutorial.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VR2LiE2F5M

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to cache the JSON response to ensure the best UI performance.  You can use something like [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to parse the results into a dictionary containing an item for each image url and text description.  You can then write the dictionary to disk and read it back later.  You could also simply write the JSON itself to a file and read it back or go so far as to use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). If you decide to dabble with Core Data I personally recommend adding [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) with it to make life MUCH easier.  You're probably making RESTful API calls to get your JSON.  In that case [RESTKit](http://restkit.org/) is very helpful as well.  [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial) has a nice intro.

This might not be the "quick & dirty" approach... but in my experience... the combination of these things help make things nicer.